# Search yesterday's tweets

Tags: r, twitter

I want to compile a dataset, consisting of tweets from Twitter over a period of several weeks.

To do so, I will have to save the tweets of every single day and save them to a csv file (and afterwards bringing them together into a single file). I plan to run the script every day and save the tweets of yesterday.

I use twitteR and after the authentication process I have the following code:

```
# today is 2015-01-14
searchResults <- searchTwitter("#goodbyenukes", n=1500, since='2015-01-13', until='2015-01-13')

# save results in dataframe and csv
tweetsDf = ldply(searchResults, function(t) t$toDataFrame())
write.csv(tweetsDf, file="2015-01-13.csv")
```

I do not want to modify the script every day so that I get yesterday's tweets. By using Sys.Date() I can tell R to use today's date. But is there a way to tell are to use yesterday's date, so that I do not have to change the script every day?

Comment: does no one know how to use Sys.Date()-1 in "since" and "until" in "searchTwitter"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You could use Sys.Date() - 1.
for more info: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Ops.Date.html

try as.character to convert it to a string, e.g.:
searchResults <- searchTwitter("#goodbyenukes", n=1500, since=as.character(Sys.Date() - 1), until=as.character(Sys.Date() - 1))

Comment: ok, thank you! so with Sys.Date() - 1 I get yesterday. That works fine for the filename but not for since and until in searchTwitter